# TortoiseSVN and Putty problems

Tags: svn, network-attached-storage

here is the situation:

successfully installed svnserver on a NAS drive accessible by LAN using this tutorial:

http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step%5Fguide%5Fto%5Finstalling%5FSubversion%5Fon%5FARM-based%5FSynology%5FProducts

The svn base directory is called svn, and the repo (dummy-name: repo_name) is inside svn.

I've edited the svnserver.conf and passwd files - and created a user as described in "Set Repository Permissions" (I've set anon-write for the sake of testing). From my workstation I try and check out the repo I've created on the NAS, using this format:

svn+ssh://IP_ADDRESS/svn/repo_name

The client attempts to connect, requests a password but fails to establish a connection.

I currently have a couple of hypotheses:

1. Tortoise is having to log in to the NAS itself first
2. I shouldn't be using an IP Address - should I use the drive letter it's mapped to, or the network name of the device?
3. TSVN needs to be configured in some way.

Tortoise is set to use TortoisePlink - when I try and assign Putty to it, it complains about the port (although I can connect and administer using Putty outside of TSVN).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> successfully installed by LAN using
>   this tutorial:

If you followed that tutorial I believe you would need to use a svn:// url to access the repository, not svn+ssh.  That tutorial has you setting up the subversion daemon.

> I shouldn't be using an IP Address -
>   should I use the drive letter it's
>   mapped to,

Will you always have local access to the repository?  Do you need this repository to be available to the world?  If you only need to use it locally perhaps you should consider simply using a file:// url.  You shouldn't need to setup any daemons to use subversion like this.

See the section in the docs about [repository URLs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls).

Comment: thanks for the response - I used svn+ssh because I thought I was having to access the repo via an ssh tunnel (being as I had to set it up using putty). I've already set up repo's using file:// - but the TSVN documentation recommends setting up a server - plus I would like to know how to do it to satisfy my O.C.D...

Comment: The problem was two fold in the end, I'd modified inetd.conf incorrectly, and used the format describe above - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may just be using the wrong protocol to access your repo. Indeed, svn+ssh is a way to access some repos, but if you followed the instructions in the above link, you should be using the svn:// protocol instead, correct?